# Speed decrease on volatile neo4j dataset

Tags: performance, neo4j, cypher

I'm using neo4j in one of my projects and have noticed that my local database (used to run test suites) becomes slower and slower over the course of time. This is a low-priority issue, as it currently does not seem to occur during real-world use (outside of running huge test suites), but for the goal of improving neo4j I figured it be best to post it nonetheless :)

As it currently stands, these are my findings:

1. the speed decrease is linked to the amount of tests executed (and therefore, the amount of created/deleted nodes)
2. the db size increases, even though each test suite clears the database* after use (indicating dead nodes remain)
3. deleting the `graph.db` file solves the issue (further proof for the dead nodes theory)

Although the problem can be easily solved in an acceptable way for a test database, I'm still worried about the production implications of this symptom for long running databases with volatile data. Granted, having a database with data as volatile as the test data is a border case, however it shouldn't be a problem at all. At minimum a solution which is production ready (I'm thinking dead node pruning) should be available, however I can find nothing of the sorts in the documentation.

Is this a known issue? I couldn't find any reference to similar issues. Any help in locating the exact cause would be greatly appreciated, as I'd like to contribute a patch if I can find (and solve) the actual problem.

---

*) the database is cleared using two separate cypher commands (to prevent occasional occurrences of [issue 27](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/27)) the following cyphers are run in order: `MATCH ()-[r]-() DELETE r` `MATCH (n) DELETE n`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've experienced the same behavior as well. We were running a heavy calculation script every 15 minutes on the entire database. That produced huge [(logical) log files](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/configuration-logical-logs.html) that seemed to decrease the performance. In order to reduce the log files, you need to set the `keep_logical_logs` property. For tests, the following might be a good setting:

```
keep_logical_logs=24 hours
```

For tests, you'd also want to consider the `ImpermanentantGraphDatabase` if an embedded database  an option. You can get it with

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j-kernel</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
    <classifier>tests</classifier>
</dependency>
```

Comment: It seems you are right! Very good find, thank you for sharing!